# Generate evenly space point geography along a linestring

Tags: statistics, geospatial, google-bigquery

I have the total number of poles in a location (a sample area) and the road geometry (linestring) of each road in the area. I can calculate the average distance between poles, I want to distribute these total number of poles evenly along the different roads (linestring). I see that ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT() can help me achieve this but I dont have this function in BigQuery.

Snippest of my road_table is attached here.
[image]
My approach is generate interpolated points along the road at regular intervals determined by the raio value that is calculated from array as show below:

SELECT road_geometry, ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT(road_geometry, ratio) AS  interpolated_points
FROM road_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY (0,1, 1/(road_length/avg_dist_pole) AS ratio
Hoping to have an output of array of POINT Geography for each record.

But ST_LINE_INTERPOLATE_POINT is not in BQ.

What other approach can I use to achieve this, beside I am not certain if this is the best approach?